# Imapclient attachment method

Tags: python, attachment, imapclient

Kindly what would be the method for message object within imapclient library,

for example, when fetching a message via UIDs, I can use `header = str(message.get_subject())`

to get the email message subject, what would be the method for attachments please?

Comment: Does the documentation address this question? What about other `imapclient` related questions here on stackoverflow? Such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24075732/read-body-of-email-using-imapclient-in-python, or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52425681/get-content-of-a-mail-imapclient, etc.

Comment: I couldn't find anything about message attachments. https://imapclient.readthedocs.io/en/2.2.0/installation.html